# Solr: Synonyms using the Managed Resources REST API

Tags: rest, solr

How do I change an initArgs value for Synonyms using the Managed Resources REST API?

In particular, I need to change the following:

`"initArgs":{"ignoreCase":false}`

... to `true`.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Managed+Resources#ManagedResources-Synonyms

I don't see any mention in the documentation about changing `initArgs`.

You can edit the file directly after it has been created, but the docs explicitly say this is not the correct way to change data in this file. (it does work however).

Comment: FYI to anyone looking at this issue: this feature is apparently not available as of Solr 5.1. You have to manually edit the managed synonyms file and set ignoreCase: true. After updates this parameter will "stick".

Answer (score 8):

found it. try&error style ;-)

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '{"initArgs":{"ignoreCase":true}}' "http://<solr-host>/solr/<core>/schema/analysis/synonyms/german"
```